# Junit java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cors.origin.value' in value "${cors.origin.value}"

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

**It is actually resolved but I will leave here solution if anyone will face the same issue. You have to configure placeholder manually like:**

```
 public EventControllerTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(eventController)
                .addPlaceholderValue("cors.origin.value", "http://localhost:4200")
                .build();
    }
```

I am trying to perform simple unit test of some method from controller but I am facing an issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'cors.origin.value' in value "${cors.origin.value}"
```

Why is that happen? it is only simple unit test so I do not have to setup whole context for this right?

My code:

request I am calling is API_V1_EVENTS_FIND_BY_GENRE:

```
public class TestApiUrlStrings {

    public static final String API_V1_EVENTS = "api/v1/events";
    public static final String API_V1_EVENTS_FIND_BY_GENRE = API_V1_EVENTS + "/Dance?page=0";
}
```

Unit Test

```
public class EventControllerTest {

    @Mock
    EventService eventService;

    @InjectMocks
    EventController eventController;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    public EventControllerTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(eventController)
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void findByGenre() throws Exception {

        EventsDTO expected = EventsDTOdatasource.getEventsDTO();

        when(eventService.findByGenre(anyString(),anyInt())).thenReturn(expected);

        mockMvc.perform(get(TestApiUrlStrings.API_V1_EVENTS_FIND_BY_GENRE)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.events", hasSize(3)));

    }

}
```

And controller

```
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin(value = "${cors.origin.value}")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EventController.API_V1_EVENTS)
public class EventController {

    public static final String API_V1_EVENTS = "api/v1/events";

    private final EventService eventService;

    public EventController(EventService eventService) {
        this.eventService = eventService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{musicGenre}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public EventsDTO findByGenre(@PathVariable String musicGenre,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNum) {

        return eventService.findByGenre(musicGenre, pageNum);
    }

    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public EventsDTO saveAll(@RequestBody EventsDTO eventsDTO) {
        return this.eventService.saveAll(eventsDTO);
    }
}
```

Why exception is pointing to CORS value where I do not even need it here?
How to resolve this? There is not much about such exception anywhere.